# Invert Result of MongoDB Query / Opposite $and operation

Tags: mongodb

This is my collection:

```
{ _id: "539b6502e9630311ad000033", user: "dummy1", x: 1, y: 1 }

{ _id: "539b64c2bdf763720900003e", user: "", x: 0, y: 1 }

{ _id: "539b653ad2a87581ff00000b", user: "dummy3", x: 1, y: 0 }

{ _id: "cPtudQJyKxffCgaZ9", user: "", x: 2, y: 5 }

{ _id: "Br8tCEwhrhG5tKwdJ", user: "dummy1", x: 1, y: 14 }

{ _id: "9AoLD6nLRnhdRfxPw", user: "dummy1", x: 8, y: 15 }
```

How to query all documents except for `{x: "1", y: "1"}` which contain `user: "dummy1"`?

I am looking for the opposite of:

```
find({user: "dummy1", "$and": [{x: 1}, {y: 1}]}).limit(10)
```

which returns:

```
{_id: "539b6502e9630311ad000033", user: "dummy1", x: 1, y: 1}
```

my guess was:

```
find({user: "dummy1", "$not": [{x: 1},{y: 1}]}).limit(10)
```

which return: No documents found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To negate a boolean AND, you can use an OR with each term negated:

```javascript
db.test.find({user: 'dummy1', $or: [{x: {$ne: 1}}, {y: {$ne: 1}}]})
```

Which outputs:

```javascript
{
    "_id" : "Br8tCEwhrhG5tKwdJ",
    "user" : "dummy1",
    "x" : 1,
    "y" : 14
}
{
    "_id" : "Br8tCEwhrhG5tKwdx",
    "user" : "dummy1",
    "x" : 3,
    "y" : 5
}
```